# Azure: Join two 5 million tables every 6 hours as quick as possible

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-bigquery, azure-sql-database, azure-cloud-services

I have first table having 5mil rows in Azure SQL DB and second table having 5mil rows in Google BigQuery.

I need to join them every 6hours and it should take minimum time.

What could be the best way to do this which should be cost effective also?

Comment: It's not clear that there is a "best way". What have you looked into so far? For such a small amount of data, it should be quick to load into BigQuery if you export it from Azure.

Comment: 2 5-Million row tables can easily be joined on a single machine.  You don't even need to pay for a scale-out platform of any sort.  In either path, most cloud providers charge you for data egress and you should consider consolidating things into a single place as one option to reduce costs.  Trying to run joins over the internet is far, far slower than running joins within a single machine.  If you end up using SQL Azure, please examine whether columnstores help your scenario as they greatly speed up analytics queries.

Comment: I dont want to replicate the Azure SQL table and to my understanding if i copy bigq table into sql altho its only insert, will take a lot of time to join in Azure SQL DB. I have searched for cosmosDB but i reckon it costs a lot. My objective is to join them and put into one store/place where powerbi can pick it because joining in powerbi i think takes a long time. Any other alternative?

Comment: Even if i replicate the Azure SQL table, I am not sure what should be the common consolidating place which could be cost effective. I have use cases where i need to join two 5mil rows many times in 6hours and it should not take more then 15-30min.

Comment: It depends on your needs, unfortunately.  If you are choosing Azure SQL DB, you want auto-management.  It can easily join this number of rows in a single join in usually seconds, not minutes.  I encourage you to do a PoC on each platform you want to use and see how fast they are and how much they cost.